# How do I request storage permission in android 6.0?

Tags: android

Here                                                           is what I have done so far, but the problem is, the                                                                                                       code never asks for permissions, no errors, no force closes. I am currently testing on android 6.0 device. I even revoked permissions in settings but it is still not asking. I have posted the full code below-

```
package com.example.pper;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private String TAG;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    isStoragePermissionGranted();
}

public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat
                    .requestPermissions(
                            this,
                            new String[] { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                            1);
            return false;
        }
    } else { // permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon
                // installation
        Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Permission: " + permissions[0] + "was "
                + grantResults[0]);
        // resume tasks needing this permission
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

check `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` - if you had the dialog before and click "never ask again" it will never request you permmission again.

> To help find situations where the user might need an explanation, Android provides a utiltity method, shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(). This method returns true if the app has requested this permission previously and the user denied the request.
>
> Note: If the user turned down the permission request in the past and
>   chose the Don't ask again option in the permission request system
>   dialog, this method returns false. The method also returns false if a
>   device policy prohibits the app from having that permission.

Comment: did you try debug / log to see where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your manifest file includes something like this:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="25" />
```

Comment: Hmm, strange, your code seems to be working fine on my device (Android 7.1.1).

Comment: I have samsung, maybe they customized their libraries